# Changing Owncloud File Permission/User/Group

Tags: php, samba, file-sharing, owncloud

How to change Owncloud settings/code to set the User/Group/Permission uploaded files get? Can it be done?

I'm running Owncloud 9.0.2 (stable) on Ubuntu.

By default, new files and directories (folder) get 0644.

I've got a Samba share as an External Storage in Owncloud. The problem is that Samba users do not have write access to the files in the share if the file was uploaded from Owncloud (since they get 0644).

Thanks.

Comment: have you find an answer?